# How to use WebRTC on Unity in order to build Android and iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc

I have to build a WebRTC app on Android and iOS, i don't have iOS programming skills, but i work a lot with Unity.

How can I use WebRTC with Unity ? I don't want to build a WebGL project.

I thought about a c# wrapper of lib WebRTC, but maybe it's already existing ? 
Is there any troubleshooting doing that ?

What i thought about would be to develop most of the UI and all with Unity and add a (native) Video WebRTC layout on it (not the best, but it could work i guess).

That's kind of tricky, but it could save me a lot of time

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to work with Unity i would recommend taking a look at [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) which is a development framework for cross platform apps using HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3. Also worth looking at is [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) which is a "HTML5 Hybrid Mobile App Framework" that builds apps using Cordova.

The reason i recommend these frameworks is because they shorten the development time for cross platform apps and have great support for WebRTC.
[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-an-audio-calling-app-with-ionic-and-phonertc/) is a guide that explains how to use WebRTC together with Ionic and [here](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc) is the WebRTC plugin for Cordova.

Comment: I'm not really used to Cordova, but i'll give it a try. Since WebRTC isn't supported by Unity android/iOS, i think it is the best solution. I'll give it a try. Thanks for your answer!